# Result of a job for a list of circuits on QISKit

Tags: programming, qiskit

Suppose `Circuits= [circuit1, circuit2, ..., circuitn]` is a list of defined circuits. Then, `job = execute(Circuits, backend=backend, shots=shots, max_credits=max_credits)` will execute a list of circuits all together. Then, one can get the result by using `job.result().get_counts`. It looks like this (with the results of the first circuit execution highlighted): 
[image]

Is there any way to extract the counts like how it usually is with only one circuit in execution?

Answer (score 3):

From the Getting started tutorial on Qiskit, it seems that you grab the result of job first and you access the counts via the function get_counts(circuit) for a specific circuit. So I would loop through Circuits and use this function on each:

```
result_submissions = job.result()
for qc in Circuits:
     counts = result_submissions.get_counts(qc)
     print(counts)
```

Comment: I'm sorry I should have mentioned probably, but I only have two circuits qc and qc5 and my list is: Circuits= [qc, qc5, qc, qc5, qc, qc5, qc, qc5], so by looking at  job.result().get_counts I get 8 different (but unexpectedly
 close) sets of values, but by looping over qc in Circuits I only get two sets of values, repeated four times.

Comment: @Mathophile-Mathochist I guess that is because the execute function on a list sample independently and the get_counts take the first result circuit as reference. Maybe you can try calling get_counts() with the parenthesis then see if you have access to the results argument which you may be able to loop through and use the get_counts() method if the ExperimentResult class has one.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the `get_counts()` function:

```
result = job_exp.result()
result.get_counts(arg)
```

The key here is that that function takes different arguments: simply an integer representing the index of the circuit on the `Circuits` list, the circuit object itself, and the circuit.name attribute (I think). You can check this [on the documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/autodoc/qiskit.result.result.html?highlight=result%20get_counts#qiskit.result.result.Result.get_counts).

So even if you have the same circuit several times in the the `Circuits` list, you can still correctly identify each circuit by using the index referring to its position on the said list.

This goes a bit late, but might still be useful for someone.